# Expression in mathematica

Tags: expression-test

i have an expression:

```
n*Subscript[e,3] Subscript[e,4] Subscript[e,7]...*Subscript[e,k]*Subscript[e,k]
```

I would evaluate it such as return n*Subscript[e,3*4*k*k+1]
n is generic Number 
Any idea?

Comment: Can you provide some more context?

Comment: thedude interval Analysis, but my question is generic

Comment: Are you aware that upper-case `N` is the name of a built-in *Mathematica* function?

Comment: @murray Yes, i edited question;)

Comment: It is still not clear what you want.

Comment: @thedude I want to return n*Subscript[e, I*j*k*..i..*] where the indices in the product are taked by expression Subscript[e,i]*Subscript[e,j]*..*Subscript[i]

Comment: Why is your expected output not `n*Subscript[e, 3*4*7*k*k]`? A little more detail is warranted, because it is difficult to tell from your example what the pattern is supposed to be.

Answer (score 4):

```
expr = n * Subscript[e, 3] * Subscript[e, 4] * Subscript[e, 7] * 
           Subscript[e, k] * Subscript[e, k + 1];

expr /. HoldPattern[
           Times[s : Repeated[Subscript[e, _]]]
        ] :> Subscript[e, Times @@ Last /@ {s}]

(* n Subscript[e, 84 k (1 + k)] *)
```